# How to check the existence of a view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to create a script that check if a view already exist.
I think that this should do this, but there just don't want to work :)

```
IF EXISTS(select * FROM system.views where name = 'view_name');
```

Any ideea about what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if you own the view then you can query user_view, else if you did not own it you can query it using all_views.

Comment: If you only have to check once, select * from YourView where 1 =2 will either crash or return the field names.  If you have to check dynamically, you might be doing something unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE V_COUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  select COUNT(*) INTO V_COUNT FROM dba_views where view_name = 'view_name'; 
  -- use dba_views or all_views tables

  IF V_COUNT > 0 THEN 
  -- your code goes here
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Hmm,  this seems to have more logic but still have some errors. Can't copy paste them here so I put them in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/DVgVbZpH

Comment: Try updated code, i thought you knew how to use them in pl/sql blocks